# How to select first several items using prototype select method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypejs

I have a code like this:

```
$('my-id').select('dd');
```

But it selects all dd from 'my-id' block. What is the best way to select only several, for example, 4 dd's from my-id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.eachSlice()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Enumerable/prototype/eachSlice/) to break the array into chunks and then take the chunk you want to work with. In the example below it is the first one.

```
var dds = $('my-id').select('dd').eachSlice(4)[0];
```